# Angular 6 - Change class with onmouseover on a div with ngFor

Tags: angular, angular6

I've this component with html:

```
    <div *ngFor='let option of options'>
      <label [ngClass]="clazz" 
         (mouseover)="clazz='highlightedOption'" 
         (mouseout)="clazz='normalOption'" 
         (click)="navigate(option)">
        {{option | uppercase}}
        <br/>
      </label>
    </div>
```

Here `options` is an `array ['x', 'y', 'z']` defined in the typescript of the same component.

The problem is, on hover, the **class (or clazz)** changes for all the three `divs` that get generated from `*ngFor`. I expect the class to change only for the hovered `div`.

I want to understand how to use `(mouseover)` with `*ngFor`, and change the class like this. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: I can confirm that I've searched for this on google, stackoverflow, reddit, github etc. I could not find a working answer for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can prepare an array, if you plan to add the class to only one div, something like below:-

```
<div *ngFor='let option of options; let i = index'>
  <label [ngClass]="clazz[i]" 
     (mouseover)="clazz[i]='highlightedOption'" 
     (mouseout)="clazz[i]='normalOption'" 
     (click)="navigate(option)">
    {{option | uppercase}}
    <br/>
  </label>
</div>
```

---

As a side note, you may also build a directive which could perform your desired functionality.

Comment: This works, only thing is that I had to define a typescript array for clazz:
public clazz: number[] = [];
I wonder if there can be an even cleaner solution. Really appreciate your suggestion!

Comment: You can try building a directive. Please follow this guide; it is similar to what you need - https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives

Comment: Sure I'll try the directive approach as well. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sure, no problem, glad to help :)

Comment: I tried the directive approach, it works great and allows much more flexibility! Thanks for your help.

Comment: @SanjayVerma No problem :)